# Is there a function that dumps order to second list, instead of modifying the first one?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm creating app for ordering list of race results from best to worst, with showing the actual position. I'm just starting in programming.

Example:

ArrayList results //[8, 9, 5, 4, 7]

should return ArrayList position (from low to high) //[4, 5, 2, 1, 3]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Primitives only know their value, so you probably want to turn the primitives into some datastructure that lets you record their original position in whatever list you had them in, before you do your sorting. Then post-sort, you can flatten the result to "only the positions" (although you probably wouldn't want to, having the associated values immediately available is far more useful)

Comment: Tried looking for one one (though I'm not English speaking+ don't have experience so it was a hard search), and I'm still trying some math, with small brakes it has alerady taken me 5 hours. If I learn something new I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to sort your result use:

```
Collections.sort(result, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

But if you need to track indexes you might need:

```
class ResultArray{
   int index;
   int value;
   public ResultArray(int i, int v){
         index = i;
         value = v;
   }
}
List<ResultArray> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        nums.add(new ResultArray(i, result.get(i)));
    }
    Collections.sort(nums, (a, b) -> a.y > b.y ? -1 : 1);
```